# Scrolling image gallery without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a scrolling image gallery as follows. The CSS lays out the images in a row that scrolls horizontally. Underneath, I have a row of the same images, but as thumbnails. I want to be able to click on a thumbnail, and scroll the correct image into view.

HTML:

```
<div class="images_container">
  <img id="image_1" src="/image1.jpg">
  <img id="image_2" src="/image2.jpg">
  <img id="image_3" src="/image3.jpg">
</div>

<div class="images_container thumbnails">
  <a href="#image_1"><img src="/image1.jpg" class="thumbnail"></a>
  <a href="#image_2"><img src="/image2.jpg" class="thumbnail"></a>
  <a href="#image_3"><img src="/image3.jpg" class="thumbnail"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.images_container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 50rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.images_container.thumbnails {
  max-height: 10rem;
}

.images_container img {
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 50rem;
}

.images_container.thumbnails img {
  height: 10rem;
}
```

This works up to a point, but jumping to the id of the image is problematic. If the larger image is even a few pixels into the visible viewport, it can't 'jump' to it, as it seems to be technically on the screen.

Is there a way I can use Javascript to 'scroll' the whole image into view when I click on it's corresponding thumbnail? I don't have access to jQuery on this project, but am happy to use JavaScript to make this work.

Comment: "without jQuery" Or "without Javascript" ?

Comment: Without jQuery. I'm happy to introduce JavaScript as necessary, and would rather do that for a better experience, we're just not using jQuery on this project.

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to introduce some Javascript. I just don't know what JS functions I should be using to scroll an image into the viewport.

Comment: I've done something like this a couple of times before, where what I did was I made each <img> live in it's own <div>, and then used CSS to keep what image was in view in track by use of an active class. So each div container was the same size, images where therefore automatically scaled to it. .image-container.active was positioned at 0,0, previous siblings were positioned -100% for left, and next siblings were positions 100% left, and the js just changed which container had .active. Will write you a fiddle, but it could take a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this , no change in CSS, i add an id in html and call to scrollTo function :

```
<script>

    function scrollTo(image_id){
        var topLeft = document.getElementById(image_id).offsetTop;
        document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft = topLeft;
    }


</script>
<div id="container" class="images_container">
  <img id="image_1" src="/image1.jpg" height="500px" width="500px">
  <img id="image_2" src="/image2.jpg"  height="500px" width="500px">
  <img id="image_3" src="/image3.jpg"  height="500px" width="500px">
</div>

<div class="images_container thumbnails">
  <a href="#image_1"><img src="/image1.jpg" class="thumbnail" onclick="scrollIntoView('image_1')"></a>
  <a href="#image_2"><img src="/image2.jpg" class="thumbnail" onclick="scrollIntoView('image_2')"></a>
  <a href="#image_3"><img src="/image3.jpg" class="thumbnail" onclick="scrollIntoView('image_3')"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep DOM cleaner I got this solution which requires only adding js

```
var elms = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail");
for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   elms[i].onclick = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      var id = this.parentNode.href.substr(this.parentNode.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 2);
      var v = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect().left;
      document.getElementsByClassName("images_container")[0].scrollLeft += v;
   }
}
```

See on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/qLm8n87z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a no (well, minimal) JS solution to a scrolling gallery. You could, in fact, remove the Javascript all together if you replaced the .active class with the :target pseudo-selector, allowing you to click your thumbnails to do the scrolling. It's just easier for me to do it this way through a fiddle

```js
function removeClass(element, className) {
  var classes = element.className.split(' ');
  var key = classes.findIndex(function(name) {
    return name == className
  });
  classes.splice(key, 1);
  element.className = classes.join(' ');
}

function addClass(element, className) {
  var classes = element.className.split(' ');
  classes.push(className);
  element.className = classes.join(' ');
}

setInterval(function() {
  var current = document.querySelector('.images .image.active');
  var next = current.nextElementSibling;

  if (!next) {
    next = document.querySelector('.images .image:first-child');
  }

  removeClass(current, 'active');
  addClass(next, 'active');
}, 1500);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  float: left;
  transition: 1s;
}

.image.active {
  left: 0%;
}

.image.active ~ .image {
  left: 100%;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='images'>
  <div class='image black active'></div>
  <div class='image red'></div>
  <div class='image blue'></div>
  <div class='image yellow'></div>
</div>
```

Essentially the way it works is by making the `div.images` container a certain height and width, and therefore all images inside it can be positioned as you want. We initially set all `.image` to `left: -100%`, so that they're completely off screen to the left. We then set `.image.active` as `left: 0` so that it's on screen. We then use the `~` selector to say that all siblings that come *after* the current (`.image.current ~ .image`) should be `left: 100%`, so completely to the right. Add in a transition, and you have a completely CSS scrolling gallery. The JS only acts as a way to change what the current active image is, and you can replace that with `:target` if you want.

I used div's, instead of img tags because it's easier to provide a POC with div's and background colors, but it's worked well with images in the past. Just put an `<img>` tag inside those `<div class='image'></div>` tags